# My USB2VGA is working - How do I configure X to use that screen?

Tags: raspbian, peripherals, xorg, modules

I have a green screen on my USB2VGA connection (DisplayLink). How do I configure X to use the screen `/dev/fb1` which exists?  I do not find an `xorg.conf`.